# FFMPEG rtsp stream add timestamp to output file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, timestamp, rtsp

I'm trying add timestamp to output file from FFMPEG but I'm getting this error.

```
Filtergraph 'drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='\%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460' was defined for video output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together
```

And my command is:

```
 ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.52:554/11 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='\%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -acodec copy -vcodec copy test.avi
```

And the output:

> ffmpeg version N-75939-g6eaf97c Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)   configuration:
>   --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfreetype
>    libavutil      55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100   
> libavcodec     57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100 
>   libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100  
>  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100 
>   libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100  
>  libswscale      4.  0.100 / 
>   4.  0.100 
>   libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100 
>   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:@192.168.1.52:554/11':  
>  Metadata:
>       
> title           : 10   Duration: N/A, start: 0.159000, bitrate: N/A
>       
> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720, 25.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>       
> Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s Filtergraph
>   'drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='\%T':
>   fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460' was defined for video output stream
>   0:0 but codec copy was selected. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be
>   used together.

Where I'm doing a mistake ?

Thank you for all reply :)

Comment: `-vcodec copy` == streamcopy. You need to re-encode to add a text overlay so choose one encoder like `libx264` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to -vcodec libx264 it said Illegal instructions.

Comment: Bad example, it might not be available in your ffmpeg build, try another (`ffmpeg -codecs`)

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about _using_ FFmpeg, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [su] or [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this command posted for ffmpeg (thanks to github user reidransom):

```sh
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec libx264 -cmp 22 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=DroidSansMono.ttf: timecode='09\:57\:00\:00': r=29.976: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -y output.mov
```

Keep in mind it's one complete line. The \ characters in the timecode option are there to enable the :'s as chars. r sets the frames per second capture rate.